# getting socket header files

Tags: c++, sockets, header

I'm new to C/C++ and I'm using it to learn the Socket API. As I was made aware, I need to include certain socket header files to be able to use the built-in functions.

```
#include <sys/socket.h> // Needed for socket creating and binding
#include <netinet/in.h> // Needed to use struct sockaddr_in
```

This is what I put at the top of my main.cpp class, and CLion says it "cannot find socket.h". I've searched for "socket header download" across the internet, but many forums say it should come with whatever C files I already have by default. I installed Cygwin yesterday as my C compiler. Do I just have to reinstall it, find some socket API packages, then reinstall CLion to use socket functions? If so, what are the packages called?

Comment: There doesn't exist a language named C/C++.

Comment: You are apparently using C++, not C. Different languages. And a source file is not a class (nor is `main` a class).

Comment: Cygwin is not a C compiler. Dealing with Cygwin may be quite challenging even for experienced developers. If you are new to C/C++ you should select a more straightforward platform to develop on. If you are using Windows then you should try to develop native Windows applications first.

Comment: To add on regarding @VTT's comment, you should rather use the MinGW development environment on Windows.

Comment: @VTT It's not just a C compiler, but it certainly includes one.

Comment: @VTT: As OP confuses C and C++, just that: The C compiler from MS is not standard compliant since more than 18 years now. It is not a good match for a beginner to learn the C langugage. And for sockets: Windows is not POSIX-compliant and follows its own way. Better use Linux or MacOS when learning sockets and other such common stuff.

Comment: "there doesn't exist a language named c/c++" how many times have i read this factual statement for the sake of being rude and unhelpful when the user didn't even make that claim to begin with. They said they are new to c/c++ implying they are new to both languages, and to no stretch of the imagination the features of both languages can be used together and are quite often. It would be one thing if they even made the claim you acted like they did, but they didn't. I know this is super old but things like this should be flagged, not upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying this socket program in Windows platform, it WON'T work for sure.

> `#include <sys/socket.h>`

- Works only in Linux/Mac Platforms.

If you are onto Windows, you need to try like :

```
#ifdef __WIN32__
# include <winsock2.h>
#else
# include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
```

Comment: It will probably work with Cygwin, which has a POSIX compatibility layer for sockets.